# Rebuild Spatial Index After Massive Changes

Tags: sqlite, gis, spatial

I have a question about spatial index.
I'm using sqlite with VirtualSpatialIndex.

The quesion is :
I have a main table that contains millions of polygons.
Let's say every 4 months I have to get a complete new snapshot of the polygons from another party.

Meaning I should delete all the records of the polygons from the main table (i.e truncate main table), and then insert all the records from the new snapshot.
That's why I need to re-build the spatial index .

How should I do it?

After checking the spatialite functions refernce I came up with the following solution.

[Spatialite functions reference](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.1.0.html)

1)Truncate main table

2)Insert new snapshot to main table

3)Use RecoverSpatialIndex('MainTable','MyGeoCol',1) to rebuild the RTree from scratch.

What do you think?
Is it right?